# Mongo count unknown amount of field labels

Tags: mongodb

assume I have following structure :

```
"KnownName" : {
    "unknownName1" : {
        "id" : "unknownName1",
        "value" : "5"
    },
    "unknownName2" : {
        "id" : "unknownName2",
        "value" : "5"
    },
    "unknownName3" : {
        "id" : "unknownName3",
        "value" : "5"
    },
    "unknownName4" : {
        "id" : "unknownName4",
        "value" : "5"
    },
    "unknownName5" : {
        "id" : "unknownName5_v2",
        "value" : "5"
    },
    "unknownName6" : {
        "id" : "unknownName6",
        "value" : "5"
    }

... many more documents as above in various ways
```

and I want to get all of these counted like this :

```
unknownName1 : 24
unknownName2 : 27
unknownName3 : 10
....
unknownName37 : 12
```

I do know my structure upon the 'KnownName' node, but within this node I can have several different labels (here unknownName 1 to 6) but there can be more or less, and they can be different by document. Typically the id in the array will have the same name as the array label but it's not a given (as in unknownName5).

I was looking for ways to get a distinct count of all these 'unknownNames' but this seems to be more challenging as expected.

Any advice on how this can be achieved (preferably using the aggregation framework)

If there is an easy way to get all (deep) children labelled as "id" in the "KnownName" tree without the need to know the unknown parent name it would work also for me. I'm aware there is no such thing as wildcards in mongo, but I'm looking for an alternative to something like KnownName.*.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) since your keys are unknown. Then you'll get an array of keys and values that can be processed using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get counts. You can also use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get dynamic keys in root object

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            unknown: { $objectToArray: "$KnownName" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$unknown"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$unknown.k",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            data: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: "$data"
            }
        }
    }
])
```